# How to show that $\{(v_1, 0), \dots, (v_m, 0), (0, w_1), \dots, (0, w_n)\} \subset V \times W$ is a basis of $V \times W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Let $V$, $W$ be vector spaces over $F\; (= \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C})$. Suppose $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\} \subset V$ is a basis of $V$ and $\{w_1, \dots, w_n\} \subset W$ is a basis of $W$. Show that
> $$
> \{(v_1, 0), \dots, (v_m, 0), (0, w_1), \dots, (0, w_n)\} 
> \subset V \times W 
> $$
> is a basis of $V \times W$.

Comment: I think that your summation is meant to be an equation. Can you edit this so that it make more sense? More MathJax help [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: FYI - "$v(1,0_W) + w(0_V,1)$" is meaningless dreck. $v$ and $w$ are vectors. There is no multiplication defined bewtween vectors and pairs consisting of a scalar and a vector from a different vector space. And this "$\sum_{i=1}^m v_1(v_i,0_W) + \sum_{i=1}^n w_1(0_V,w_i)$" is just doubling down, as now you want to multiply vectors by a pair of a vector in this vector space and vector in another vector space. Just what do you think this means??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $v_i$ and the $w_j$ form a basis for $V$ and $W$ respectively.

It follows that
$$ v = \sum_i \lambda_i v_j$$
$$ w = \sum_j \mu_j w_j$$
for some $\lambda_i,\mu_j \in F.$ As you noticed we have
$$ (v,w) = (v,0) + (0,w)$$
and combining this last identity with
$$(v,0) = \sum_i \lambda_i (v_i,0)$$
$$(0,w) = \sum_j \mu_j (0,w_j).$$
we prove that the set spans $V \times W$.

---

To prove that the set is a basis we must still prove that the set is linearly independent. That is we must prove that

$$ \sum_i \lambda_i(v_i,0) + \sum_{j} \mu_j (0,w_j) = (0,0) \implies \lambda_i = \mu_j = 0 \forall i,j.$$

To see that this is the case note that

$$  \sum_i \lambda_i(v_i,0) + \sum_{j} \mu_j (0,w_j) = (0,0) \iff \sum_i \lambda_i v_i = 0  \text{ and } \sum_{j} \mu_j w_j = 0$$
and recall that the $v_i$'s and $w_j$'s are linearly independent since they form a basis for $V$ and $W$ respectively.